# making a prediction with "tree augmented naive bayes" model or "tan" through caret package of R

Tags: r, tree, caret

I am trying to use "tree augmented naive bayes" model or "tan"  in R. I found documentation of CARET package but it seems the default settings are not working and I need to do some extra data preparation. I was wondering if someone has a code + a data sample in whine someone used "tan" for model training and prediction then I can see and learn from.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/models/files/tan.R

Comment: it is just a structure. I need to have a sample data and working code

Comment: Can you give us something to work off... show us what you tried and what (specifically) isn't working about defaults? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example